# Copy folders using csv in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am fairly new to powershell with little to no experience in scripting. I have a task to copy folders from source to destination but it has some tricky part in it.
I have one source folder C:\source\ where all the folders and subfolders are resided.

[image]

And I have a csv file where I have two separate columns to copy from source to destination.

C:\dest\company1\

C:\dest\company2\

IE two different companies have folders in same source folder so need to copy them and paste it in different destination folders.

[image]

Here is the code I tried with some understanding from the internet.

```
$source       = Get-Childitem "C:\source"
$destination1 = "C:\dest\company1\"
$destination2 = "C:\dest\company2\"
$csv          = import-csv "C:\Scripts\copytask.csv"

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    if($source -contains $row.company1){
        robocopy "C:\source\$($row.company1)*" $destination1 /E 
    }
    elseif($source -contains $row.company2){
        robocopy "C:\source\$($row.company2)*" $destination2 /E 
    }
}
```

And I am not getting any output or copying when I run the script.

Comment: Maybe start trying `if($source.Name -match $row.company1){ dir "C:\source\$($row.company1)*" }`? Or `Copy-Item -WhatIf "C:\source\$($row.company1)*" $destination1` (I'd guess that `"C:\source\$($row.company1)*"` isn't well-formed)

Comment: The debugger is your friend.  Use it.